# How do I temporary block someone from sending emails in the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail

I know Gmail has a spam and phishing filter but some emails I mark as such in the past still make it through anyway. Anyway, how do you undo such a thing?  I'm receiving emails from an individual who I need to block temporarily as they refuse to stop but I need to check that account for other emails and so I end up reading the subject line.  Is there any way to temporarily block an address or hide it somehow? I do not want a permanent block.

OS: 4.1
Galaxy S3

Answer (score 0):

That is possible.

Just create a filter where mails from the adress xyz immediately will be deleted.

As soon as you want to receive the mails again just delete the filter.

(When you create a filter in the gmail web interface the filters take effect everywhere; on your galaxy, too.)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please add more instructions as images may not be up forever.

Comment: One *important* note is that creating the filter has to be done from the Gmail web since the Gmail app doesn't support creating filters directly from the app.